# How to use FINDSTR to find a string in value of a variable?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to use **FINDSTR** with a variable instead of a file?

I've tried researching this but my knowledge on batch isn't good enough yet.

I've made most of my batch file work flawlessly for what I need, but I'm having trouble extracting part of a string variable into a new variable.

The original variable for example would be `S02E12 - Charge!`. I would like to extract `02` to `ep_seas`, `12` to `ep_num`, and `Charge!` to `ep_name`. I have it working right now if that's the exact pattern of names, but I've come across some files that are in this pattern: `S02E124 - Charge #2!`

Is there a way I can dynamically get the values I need regardless of their length?

My idea was to use **FINDSTR** to search between the `S` and the `E`, then between `E` and space   (or `-`), then between `-` and the end. I'm not sure how I would proceed with this though.

Does anyone have a solution I can look into or can someone provide an example?

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set mkvmerge="C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/mkvmerge.exe"
set "output_folder=%cd%\Muxing"
for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set fi=%%a
    set ep=%%~na
    call :merge
)
goto :eof

:merge
set ep_name=%ep:~9%
set ep_num=%ep:~4,2%
set ep_seas=%ep:~2,1%
call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%ep%.mkv" --track-name "0:%ep_name%" --language 0:und --default-track 0:yes --track-name "1:[JAP]" --language 1:jpn --default-track 1:yes --track-name "2:[ENG]" --language 2:eng --default-track 2:yes --forced-track 2:yes "%fi%" --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2 --title "Fate Zero - Episode %ep_num%"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Read up on the `FOR /F` command and the `DELIMS` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this code for your task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "output_folder=%CD%\Muxing"
for /R %%I in (*.mkv) do (
    set "fi=%%I"
    set "ep=%%~nI"
    call :merge
)
goto :EOF

:merge
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=ES- " %%A in ("%ep%") do (
    set "ep_seas=%%A"
    set "ep_num=%%B"
    set "ep_name=%%C"
)
"%ProgramFiles%\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%output_folder%\%ep%.mkv" --track-name "0:%ep_name%" --language 0:und --default-track 0:yes --track-name "1:[JAP]" --language 1:jpn --default-track 1:yes --track-name "2:[ENG]" --language 2:eng --default-track 2:yes --forced-track 2:yes "%fi%" --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2 --title "Fate Zero - Episode %ep_num%"
goto :EOF
```

The command **FOR /F** as used here parses the string in double quotes which is the file name.

The option `"tokens=1,2* delims=ES- "` results in splitting up the file name strings `S02E12 - Charge!` and `S02E124 - Charge #2!` into 3 substrings using the 4 specified characters as delimiters.

1. Token 1 is `02` for both file names assigned to specified loop variable `A`.
2. Token 2 is `12` and `124` for the two file names assigned to next loop variable after `A` according to [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table which is `B`.
3. Token 3 is everything after the delimiters after token 2 which is `Charge!` and `Charge #2!` for the two files assigned to next but one loop variable `C`.

You know now why loop variables are case-sensitive while environment variables are not case-sensitive. The specified loop variable defines which characters the next loop variables have on using `for /F` with more than one token/substring.

`*` appended to a token number **X** means rest of the string/line after the delimiters after substring **X** should be assigned to next loop variable without any further splitting on delimiters. So the string after `S02E12 -`  and `S02E124 -`  can contain also delimiter characters and is nevertheless assigned completely to loop variable `C`.

Please note that a string starting with E or S after hyphen and space is interpreted also as delimiter and therefore missing in string assigned to loop variable `C`. The **FOR** loop in subroutine `merge` could be replaced by following code to get a working solution for a file name like `S03E48 - Extended Version.mkv`.

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=- " %%A in ("%ep%") do (
    set "ep_name=%%B"
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=ES" %%C in ("%%A") do (
        set "ep_seas=%%C"
        set "ep_num=%%D"
    )
)
```

The outer loop assigns `S03E48` to loop variable `A` and `Extended Version` to loop variable `B`. The inner loop splits up `S03E48` once again into `03` assigned to loop variable `C` and `48` assigned to loop variable `D`.

By the way: The directory separator on Windows is `\` and not `/` as on Unix/Linux/Mac although Windows kernel functions support also file/directory paths with `/` with automatic correction to `\`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

One last note:

It is possible to use **FINDSTR** on an environment variable for example with:

```
echo %ep% | findstr /R "^S[0123456789][0123456789]"
```

But **FINDSTR** never outputs just the matching string. It always outputs the entire line containing the found string. So **FINDSTR** is of no help here for splitting the file name up into separate parts.